# Analysing Crazyhouse Games

Tags: software, chess-variants, crazyhouse

I have recently started playing crazyhouse on chess.com. For my normal chess games, I download my chess games in PGN format. Then open them up in chessbase 13 and from within chessbase load up the UCI-compatible stockfish engine to analyse the games. Ideally, I would like to store my crazyhouse games in chessbase too and call up an engine supporting crazyhouse. But for some reason, chessbase doesn't like crazyhouse PGN files. My first question is whether there is a way to analyze crazyhouse games in Chessbase? If not, is there a database program that can handle both normal chess and crazyhouse games? It should also allow loading of UCI-compatible chess engines. I do not need all the advanced database features of chessbase. More important to me is a single consolidated software to store and analyze my games in normal chess and crazyhouse.

Comment: Try lichess. They have analysis.

Comment: I am looking for a standalone software. Lichess is a website, right?

Comment: Lichess is free, and the analysis isn't even made on your computer, so its only hard if you don't have internet. But you needed internet to post this question! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XBoard](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/)/[WinBoard](http://hgm.nubati.net/) and [PyChess](http://pychess.org/) both work well with [Stockfish for crazyhouse](https://github.com/ddugovic/Stockfish). I mostly use XBoard for analyzing crazyhouse games and positions (when I do not use lichess, e.g., to run Stockfish more efficiently locally instead of in the browser or to test experimental Stockfish versions).

Software for standard chess like ChessBase does not work with variants.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept to give up the use of a graphical interface, you can analyze your games with python-chess-annotator:

https://github.com/rpdelaney/python-chess-annotator

It is a python script that uses an UCI engine to analyze a game in a pgn file. It will give you in output a pgn file with the annotations. It works with every chess variant supported by python-chess, and Crazyhouse is supported. You can use Stockfish Crazyhouse to analyze.